# Fail to delete API Management service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I made 'API Management service' but I can't delete it.
I tried to delete it in the portal, I got this message.

> 9:47 PM
>
> Succeeded: 0, Failed: 1, Canceled: 0.
>
> Error details
>
> az532test3: The API Service az532test3 is transitioning at this time.
> Please try the request again later. (Code: ServiceLocked)

and, if I click the api management service, there is delete button unavailable...

Please help me to find a way to delete it.

Comment: I just checked and it is gone now!  As Pieter mentioned, it can take a while to provision.

Comment: You are right!! I finally could delete it after around 1 hour.

Answer (score 4):

Any chance it is still provisioning? An API Management service can take up to an hour to provision/deploy.

Answer (score 1):

The message is self-explanatory. You cannot delete api management service while it is in a transitioning state like activation, updating or upgrading. You have to wait until it back to active state.

Based on the logs, I guess you were trying to delete while your service was getting activated. It took 38 mins for activation to complete.